# Is this a good login system? Can I improve it?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, authentication

My current system works like this:

Registering

1. The user types in the email he wants to use.
2. The user types the password.
3. User clicks ok, then the email and password are emailed to my email account with javascript
4. I check my email and I find the user's email and password.
5. I put the email and password into my mysql database. I also put in a random ID into my database

Logging in

1. User types his email and password.
2. If the password is correct, the user gets an email sent to him with javascript.
3. The email contains a link, like http://mywebsite.com/loggedin?id=INSERT_ID_HERE and the ID is the random ID in my mysql database from step 5.
4. Then the website stores a cookie in PHP that says user is logged in.

Is this a good system? Is there any way to make it better?

Comment: `email and password are emailed` bad

Comment: why is that bad? I don't understand

Comment: The question doesn't contain any technical details. How exactly you're storing passwords? Why do you email it? How you're emailing *with javascript* o_O?

Comment: Yes it says that I used PHP and javascript and mysql!

Comment: You should have the server automatically store the username and password. That would be a standard system.

Comment: So you used it, what do you want from us?

Comment: What type of project is this? Why do yu have to add the user by yourself?

Comment: can I make it better and how?

Comment: This system has several big flaws and you should rework it (and kudos for asking). E-Mailing passwords in clear text is super bad. Users' passwords are usually hashed; you as the owner of the site should never get to see them.

Comment: but then how do I store the password if I don't see it?

Comment: You usually store it directly in the PHP database when the user enters it in a form. It's usually hashed at that point and then saved right away. No need to take the extra step with the E-Mail

Comment: Not hashing password is bad because if a hacker were to get access to your database, they could not just compromise your system, but other systems your users might be on.

Comment: "can I make it better and how?" --- we don't know how exactly you've implemented it, thus it's not possible to provide any advice.

Comment: ooh but how do I store stuff in my database with PHP? I don't know how, and how do I "hash" the password? (thanks, that sounds much easier)

Comment: @AwesomeCoder: "I don't know how" --- have you ever heard of http://google.com? It really makes no sense to explain it for millionth time here

Comment: ok I will try to google it

Comment: See e.g. http://tinsology.net/2009/06/creating-a-secure-login-system-the-right-way/ It uses the outdated `mysql` database layer, but at least it uses it properly. I don't know a good tut that uses PDO

Comment: this is a very bad login system.

Comment: First thing wrong with it. You dpn't need to know the user's password.

Comment: ok tntu it is bad :( everyone is telling me that, I thought it was good!

Comment: Do a search for "hash salt authentication PHP" in your favourite search engine, there should be loads of resources.

Comment: No This is not a good login system. Yes you can and should improve it.

Comment: this is not a good answer, you can and should improve it.

Comment: try this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kyQGBABA38&list=PLE134D877783367C7 i guaranteed you when your done in 7 hours you will have a good start

Comment: Kudos for asking the community a question like this, and exposing yourself to the subsequent (constructive and pointless) criticism. Keep up doing that, keep on learning and don't be put off! I wish more of us had this attitude.

Answer (score 1):

**Why email when you can just store to database?** Only if you send a confirmation link to verify the email address. And that needs to be done from PHP not JavaScript.

**Never store plain text password.** Hash it with [**crypt**()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) to keep the operation expensive in resources (slow).

**Why use ID vs. cookies? Why is JavaScript sending emails in the equation at all?** Store a session hash in a cookie. Verify against username, password and a salt. I also use UserAgent + IP to kill any XSS attempt. And would be great to have a session table just to prevent MySQL from doing hashing on many rows. This way with right indexing, you can have as many users as you want and still be snappy about looking up and validating the current session.

There's many ways to approach user authentication and sessions. None of them matches yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Have a HTML form where the user submits the details.
2. Use php to validate the input
3. Check the email address is not already in the database
4. Insert the new details into your database
5. Send an email confirmation to the user using the php 'mail' function (not essential but a good touch)

6 once they log in set a php 'session' variable to 'logged in'

Comment: quite a few more things he should be doing